# tengo problemas con parámetros por valor y referencia y recursividad

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión, parametros

Sólo pido que me ayuden en como crear la función y que me compile para sacar la raíz de polinomio, ya que al momento de solicitar datos en la función no me deja.

Éste es el código, todo esta bien sólo me falta crear la función para hacer la raíz.

Agradecería que me orientaran para saber cuál es mi error o como hacer bien la sintaxis al momento de crear la función de manera correcta.

mi error va al momento de crear una funcion leer los datos a,b,c en la funcion raiz de polinomio y retornar el resultado, eh puesto mi propia idea pero al crear la funcion pero algo falla, solo pido que me orienten para saber como resolverlo

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

// declarar protitipos de funciones AQUI
int raizdepolinomio(float &a, float &b, float &c);
int fibonacci( int j);
main()
{
   int x,n,op;
   float X1,X2,a,b,c;

   op=1;
   while(op!=3){
        printf("\n -- MENU DE OPCIONES --");
        printf("\n 1) Calcular 2 raices de un polinomio cuadrado");     
        printf("\n 2) Calcular un numero de la serie de FIBONACCI");        
        printf("\n 3) TERMINAR y SALIR");       
        printf("\n ingrese numero de opción:-> ");      
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                printf("\n... Calculando raices de un polinomio cuadrático");
                printf("\n se usara la formula general INGRESE LOS 3 COEFICIENTES");
                printf("\n ingrese coneficiente a: ");
                scanf("%f",&a);
                printf("\n ingrese coneficiente b: ");
                scanf("%f",&b);
                printf("\n ingrese coneficiente c: ");
                scanf("%f",&c);
                X1=raizdepolinomio(a,b,c);
                X2=a;
                printf("\n ... las 2 raices del polinomio son: ");
                printf("\n X1= %f y X2= %f \n",X1,X2);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\n... Calculando el numero N de la serie de FIBONACCI");
                printf("\n se usara una función recursiva");
                printf("\n ingrese el numero N a calcular: ");
                scanf("%d",&x);
                n=fibonacci(x);
                printf("\n El N numero de la serie de fibonacci es:-> %d",n);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\n seleccionó salir, el programa TERMINARÁ ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n Error... ha seleccionado una opcion incorrecta, intente de nuevo");      
        }
   }
   printf("\n PROGRAMA TERMINADO ... pulse [enter]");
   getch();
   
}

// PROGRAMAR LAS FUNCIONES AQUI
int raizdepolinomio(float &a, float &b, float &c){
    float r,p,i;
    r = ((b*b)-(4*b*c));
    p = 2*a;
    i = -b + sqrt(r)/2*a;
    a=i;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, StackOverflow es para ayudar a solucionar problemas relacionados con programacion, tu estas pidiendo que te revuelvan el ejercicio y la gente no va a estar dispuesta por lo general, te recomiendo que busques en internet como solucionar esos problemas que propones y en caso de error y no saber como avanzar se te brindará ayuda desde el foro, un saludo.

Comment: Indicanos donde crees que esta el error, o cual es tu duda, no vamos a corregir todo el codigo o hacer tus deberes.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los parámetros de entrada y qué esperas recibir como salida?

Comment: no busco que me corrigan todo el codigo, solo puse todo el codigo para que no exista confusion al momento de ver una parte, pero como dije busco que me orienten para crear una funcion en este caso de un parametro,

Answer (score 0):

cambia tu declaración de **int raizdepolinomio(...)** como **float[] raizdepolinomio(...)**

En tu método

```
// PROGRAMAR LAS FUNCIONES AQUI
float raizdepolinomio(float &a, float &b, float &c){
   float[2] raices;
   float r,p,i;
   r = ((b*b)-(4*b*c));
   p = 2*a;
   i = -b + sqrt(r)/2*a;
   raices[0] = i;
   i = -b - sqrt(r)/2*a;
   raices[1] = i;
   return raices; // no olvides poner tu return, luego en tu main solo lee el valor 0 y 1 del array.
}
```